# Illegal Characters appended to javascript file

Tags: javascript, character

I think my apache webserver has got problem.  I can't reference `jquery.js`

I get the following errors:

With chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

With firefox:

```
Error: illegal character
Source File: http://xxxxxxxxx/test/javascript/jquery.js
Line: 1
Source Code:
�Hz�ÚH[9�R
```

Below is my test html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doclick(){
            jQuery('#hello').attr('value', "mmmmef")
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" name="hello" id="hello" value="hello" onclick="doclick();" />
</body>
</html>
```

It is not only happening to `jquery.js`, these illegal characters are being appended to all `js` and `css` files.

I login with ssh and view these `js` and `css` files with `vi` command, but there are none of these characters. But when I try to download or view/edit with FTP clients Filezilla or CuteFTP, these illegal characters are included.

What's wrong with my server?  The same code can run in my local windows server and another centos server.

Comment: Tell the real address, not xxxxxxxxx which does not exist and may be handled by browsers by appending .com, resulting in a porn site address. We cannot see the internals, but with a URL, we could at least see the HTTP headers and could deduce which version of jquery is being used.

Comment: The xxxxxxxx in url is IP address of my server.  My server is in my internal network and I access via IP.  e.g. http://192.168.1.98/test.   It is not related to jquery version, because at the top of all js and css files, these illegal chars are appended.

Comment: There’s little hope of getting help with your server configuration if we cannot even see all the symptoms. Your description of Firefox behavior seems to say that garbage characters appear at the start of the .js file, and as its sole content, not appended. You really need to consult someone who can take a look inside the server.

Comment: I note that when the reference files js/css with Content-Length less than 2654 byte are not error occur.
When content length greater than or eqaul 2654, this illegal char error occur.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution at

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/apache-223-corrupt-file-download-issue.html

Just open httpd.conf and put below lines

```
            EnableMMAP off
            EnableSendfile off
```

then

```
            # /sbin/service httpd restart
```

Comment: Great, I was just punching out an answer leading to a post similar to the above! Not too clued up in Apache, so was just trying to give a few leads! Great work though!

Comment: @zawmn83 I am also getting the same error, how to resolve in tomcat            

癡爠浥湵楤猽湥眠䅲牡礨≶敲瑩捡汭敮產⤠⼯䕮瑥爠楤⡳⤠潦⁕䰠浥湵猬⁳数慲慴敤⁢礠捯浭慳ഊ癡爠獵扭敮畯晦獥琽ⴲ ⽏晦獥琠潦⁳畢浥湵猠晲潭⁭慩渠浥湵 for all the js files

Comment: Worked also for nginx, `sendfile off;` in nginx.conf "http" section.