# Illegal Characters appended to some javascript files

Tags: java, javascript, html, tomcat, struts2

I am  not able to find where the problem, it is with js files or server.It is fine with some pages, but it is not loading js files in firefox.
with firefox:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character

癡爠浥湵楤猠㵛≶敲瑩捡汭敮產崻 ⽅湴敲⁩搨猩⁯映啌⁭敮畳Ⱐ獥灡牡瑥搠批⁣潭浡猍੶慲⁳畢浥湵潦晳整‽‭㈠⼯佦晳整⁯映獵扭敮畳⁦牯洠浡楮⁭ 
cssver...menu.js (line 1, col 7)

SyntaxError: illegal character  

⼯䉥汯眠晵湣瑩潮⁩猠畳敤⁴漠晩汬⁴桥⁓異灬楥牓畢⁃慴敧潲礠乡浥猠摲潰摯睮⸊晵湣瑩潮⁳敬散瑟潮䍨慮来⡭慩湓異灎慭攩笊†ਠ†
Mariti...tory.js (line 1)

SyntaxError: illegal character

晵湣瑩潮⁣汯獥浥⠩ഊ笍ਉउ␨∣汢潸∩⹦慤敏畴⠢獬潷∩㬍ਉउ␨∣执∩⹦慤敏畴⠢獬潷∩㬍ਉउ␨∮汩獴扯硤慴慢慮欢⤮捳猨≶楳楢楬楴礢Ⱒ    
popup.js (line 1, col 4)

SyntaxError: illegal character

晵湣瑩潮⁩湩琨⤠笍੶慲⁤楶栠㴠摯捵浥湴⹧整䕬敭敮瑂祉搨❢慮湥爧⤮潦晳整䡥楧桴㬍੩映⡤潣畭敮琮来瑅汥浥湴䉹䥤⠧楮湥牣潮瑥湴桥慤敲摡
```

This is my jsp page

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"  import="java.util.*, com.sym.imu.model.AddSupplierModel" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/popup.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/popup.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>

<html:html>
    <%!
        String[] ch = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    %>

    <html:form action="/searchServiceProviderDetails" method="post">

        <%
                List<String> serviceProvider_Details_List = new ArrayList<String>();
                serviceProvider_Details_List = (List)session.getAttribute("details_List");
                session.removeAttribute("details_List");

                if(serviceProvider_Details_List!=null && serviceProvider_Details_List.size()>0){
           %>
           <script>
               $(document).ready(function() {
               statcode();
                });

           </script>
           <div id="lbox" class="lightboxresult" style="width:550px;">
                     <div class="ligtboxhead">
                         <div class="ligtboxheadtext"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(0)%></div>
                          <div  class="ligtboxheadclose" ><img src="images/Close.gif" width="8px" height="8px" align="right" onclick="closeme()"/></div>
                     </div>
                          <table style="width:100%;" cellspacing="6" align="left" >
                         <%
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(2)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorDoorNo"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(2)%>
                             </td></tr>

                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(3)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorStreet"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(3)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <% }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(4)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorCity"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(4)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <% }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(5)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorState"/></td><td  class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(5)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(6)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td style="width:50%;text-align:right;" class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorCountry"/></td><td style="width:50%; text-align:left;" class="fieldiv14"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(6)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(7)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorPinCode"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(7)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(8)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorLandPhone"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(8)%>
                          </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(9)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorMobilePhone"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(9)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(10)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td  class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorFax"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(10)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(11)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td  class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorEmailID"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(11)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(12)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td  class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorURL"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(12)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(1)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td  class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorHeadOffice"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(1)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(13)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td  class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorContactPerson"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(13)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%     }
                                if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(14)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td  class="fieldiv14"><bean:message key="Label.AddManufacturersVendorDesc"/></td><td class="fieldiv15"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(14)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%   
                                }if(serviceProvider_Details_List.get(15)!=null){
                          %>
                         <tr><td class="fieldiv14" style="color:maroon;"><bean:message key="Label.UpdatedDate"/></td><td class="fieldiv15" style="color:maroon;"><%=serviceProvider_Details_List.get(15)%>
                             </td></tr>
                         <%
                                }
                          %>
                     </table>
                 </div>
 <div id="bg"></div>

           <% serviceProvider_Details_List.clear();
                }%>
           <div id="flashbanner1" style="margin-top:-15px;">
            <div class="headercontent" id="innercontentheader">
                  <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=A"  class="headercontent">A</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=B"  class="headercontent">B</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=C"  class="headercontent">C</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=D"  class="headercontent">D</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=E"  class="headercontent">E</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=F"  class="headercontent">F</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=G"  class="headercontent">G</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=H"  class="headercontent">H</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=I"  class="headercontent">I</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=J"  class="headercontent">J</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=K"  class="headercontent">K</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=L"  class="headercontent">L</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=M"  class="headercontent">M</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=N"  class="headercontent">N</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=O"  class="headercontent">O</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=P"  class="headercontent">P</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=Q"  class="headercontent">Q</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=R"  class="headercontent">R</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=S"  class="headercontent">S</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=T"  class="headercontent">T</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=U"  class="headercontent">U</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=V"  class="headercontent">V</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=W"  class="headercontent">W</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=X"  class="headercontent">X</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=Y"  class="headercontent">Y</a>
                | <a href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?getSPNames_Location=getSPNames_Location&letter=Z"  class="headercontent">Z</a>
            </div>
            <div id="innercontent">
                <div id="addsub"><br><br>

                    <%
                List<List> spNameAndLocation_List = new ArrayList<List>();

                spNameAndLocation_List = (List<List>) session.getAttribute("spNameAndLocation_List");

                if (spNameAndLocation_List != null && spNameAndLocation_List.size() > 0) {

                    Iterator itr_List = spNameAndLocation_List.iterator();

                    while (itr_List.hasNext()) {

                        List<String> spNameAndLocation_TreeSet = new ArrayList<String>();

                        spNameAndLocation_TreeSet = (List) itr_List.next();

                        String serviceProviderName = (String) spNameAndLocation_TreeSet.get(0);
                        String serviceProviderLocation = (String) spNameAndLocation_TreeSet.get(1);
                        String addressID = (String) spNameAndLocation_TreeSet.get(2);
                        int value = 1;
                    %>
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                                <html:hidden property="sp_Name" name="sp_Name" value="<%=serviceProviderName%>" ></html:hidden>
                            <td style="color:blue;" id="Name"><a  href="searchServiceProviderDetails.do?listSPDetails=listSPDetails&value=<%=value%>&addressID=<%=addressID%>" id="sp_Name"><%=serviceProviderName%></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-style:italic;font-size:smaller;"><%=serviceProviderLocation%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <% }
            }else { %>
            <div style="margin-left:230px;margin-top:60px;">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="color:red;font-size:medium;vertical-align:middle;" id="Name">No Service Providers available</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
                <% }
                %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </html:form>
</html:html>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666416/illegal-characters-appended-to-javascript-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files need to be saved as UTF-8 and when you use them in your JSP you should specify the charset

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
```